# How to get specific date in php

Tags: php, date

I want to get UTC time as in below format.

> 2017-09-12T10:14:00.000Z

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official documentation on this subject : [Link here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please people, just TRY looking at the docs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> c | ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5) | 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00

```
$formattedDate = date("c");
```